# How to install last stable version of Gambas?

Tags: gambas3

On Ubuntu 14, how to install the latest stable version of the rapid application development Gambas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a Terminal window and type: *sudo apt-get install gambas3*.

Gambas is available in Ubuntu's official repositories. In Ubuntu 14 you can also install it using Ubuntu Software Center or Synaptic.

Be aware that Ubuntu 16.04 no longer uses Ubuntu Software Center, it uses Gnome Software instead. And you can't find Gambas in Gnome Software.

Comment: Oops, that was easy. Shame on me.